# What does 何分くらい右往左往していた？ mean?

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

> **「（踏切{ふみきり}に）入っていって後{うし}ろで標識{ひょうしき}をなぎ倒{たお}して、前{まえ}の車輪{しゃりん}がおそらく線路{せんろ}に落{お}ちるという感{かん}じ。（Ｑ．何分{なんふん}くらい右往左往{うおうさおう}していた？）僕{ぼく}が見{み}てからは２０分{ぷん}」 （目撃者{もくげきしゃ}）**

1. "The front wheel probably fell on the track", if a car gets stuck on the railroad, wouldn't the front wheel get stuck on the track, not fall on it. So in Japanese, someone can say, "the tyres/vehicle fell on the track", instead of "the vehicle drove onto the track and got stuck"?
2. Why did the witness say "go back and forth" for 20 minutes? So, an accident happens, and the witness spun in a circle back and forth for 20 minutes?

Comment: I guess we need "the source of the news "to figure out what the witness says. Is this the one : [京急衝突のトラックは２０分立往生、強引に踏切進入か](https://news.tbs.co.jp/newseye/tbs_newseye3769935.html) you are questioning?

Comment: Yeah that news article today, even the international media didn't bother to translate the witnesses account, probably because they have incompetent translators.

Answer (score 1):

They’re asking about the truck, not what the witness did. “How long did [the truck] spun its wheels [trying to get out]”? would be my guess. Although if it was indeed 20 minutes and the railway company was not notified in time to stop the train that’s a bit hard to believe so it’s probably something else.

Comment: You could be right. Articles like these require an advanced knowledge of all the little... ism's of the language to be thoroughly understood. I only glanced at the article and understood most of it, but the witnesses speak was a little too deep for my current understanding ability. This really requires a look from a paid translator, but they're too busy making $money$ so we are left in the dust.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't often hear 車輪が線路に落ちる, but some people may say it like that. I say 車輪が線路にはまる.
2. First, the truck seems to have got stuck in a narrow road along the railroad. The truck seems to have been turning back a steering wheel some times there for 20 minutes. Then, the truck seems to have got stuck in the track.

Source: https://news.tbs.co.jp/newseye/tbs_newseye3769935.html

Comment: Thanks for the help! I guess the witness was trying to say maybe that the trucker was fidgeting with the steering wheel. "Motohashi apparently struggled to make a right turn to enter the crossing from a narrow side road, with video footage taken by a security camera near the site showing him repeatedly turning the steering wheel of the 12-meter-long truck and moving it backwards and forward, a Keikyu official said."